# How to do a vertical alignment on a label in Birt report(text rotation)

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

How to do a verical alignment on a label in Birt report.I know for chart it is possible to rotate the label.How can do it in a report.I need a vertical alignment on column header(ie label).Can anyone pls share the technique

Comment: Are you talking about label orientation ? or cell's vertical alignment ? these are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plug-in that you can get on the BIRT Exchange marketplace that will create a rotated text element, in the palette, that you can use in your report design.  It is a free download.  Just place the plug-in in the plugins folder and restart Eclipse.

http://www.birt-exchange.com/be/marketplace/app-showcase/?app=22

If the above link should ever not work, you can also find the project on Eclipse Labs:
http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/birt-controls-lib/

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this as well, since there is an alternative to the other solution posted.

Depending on your output type, you can also use CSS. **But please note, this only works for web-viewers!** Any other format will disregard it. What you need to do is add an external style sheet to the report with similar CSS code to this, and then tag some dynamic text with the CSS.

```
div.vertical
{
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should make a vertical align text on microsoft Word.
2. Take a screenshot of that field.
3. Open Report Design on Eclipse
4. There is a image option under Report Items in birt
5. You can insert that screenshot image into the field you want vertical align text.